# Criterion for a signed measure to be positive

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, compactness

I am reading a proof in which I do not understand the following claim:

> Let $K$ be a compact metric space and let $M(K)$ be the set of signed Borel measures on $K$. Then the set $P(K)$ of positive Borel measures on $K$ is given by
>   $$ P(K) = \bigcap_{f \in C(K), \, \, f \geq 0} \bigg\{ \mu \in M(K) \,  \bigg| \int_K f \, d \mu \geq 0 \bigg\}.$$

The $( \subseteq)$ side is trivial. For the reverse inclusion, since any indicator function of an open set can be approximated by continuous functions, it follows that
$$ \bigcap_{f \in C(K), \, \, f \geq 0} \bigg\{ \mu \in M(K) \,  \bigg| \int_K f \, d \mu \geq 0 \bigg\} \subseteq  \big\{ \mu \in M(K) \, \, \big| \, \, \mu (U) \geq 0, \text{ for any open set } U \big\}.$$ But the problem is that for general signed measures, the collection
$$ \big\{ \mu \in M(K) \, \, \big| \, \, \mu (U) \geq 0, \text{ for any open set } U \big\}$$
does not necessarily form a d-system. Hence, I am not sure how to complete the proof. Any ideas?

Comment: Suppose $\nu \notin P(K)$. Then there is a Borel set $A\subset K$ with $\nu(A) < 0$. Can you conclude that there is a nonnegative $f \in C(K)$ with $\int_K f\,d\nu < 0$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Exactly, that's what I do not know how to show: For general signed measures, we don't necessarily have monotonicity, so I guess we can't approximate Borel sets by open sets from above .....

Comment: Implicit in the notation is that $\int f\,d\mu$ _exists_ for every $f\in C(K)$. So you must be talking about _finite_ signed measures. A finite signed measure on a compact metric space is automatically regular (because every open set is a countable union of compact sets - see somewhere in Folland. In any case, in this sort of context when people talk about measures they usually mean regular measures.) Which is to say that $\mu^++$ and $\mu^-$ are regular - you _can_ approximate sets from the outside by open sets...